# Program runs in Eclipse, doesn't run at command line

Tags: java, eclipse

Hey I wrote a simple program in Eclipse:

```
package hw;

public class Assignment02Q01Sec01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("No arguments!");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(args[args.length - 1].charAt(args[args.length -1].length() - 1));
    }

}
```

It runs fine when selecting the 'Run' menu in Eclipse but fails when running from command line:

```
c:\Users\ghostcow\workspace\hw\bin\hw>java Assignment02Q01Sec01
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Assignment02Q01Sec01
(wrong name: hw/Assignment02Q01Sec01)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: I'm in my class path in cmd, and '.' is included in the CLASSPATH env variable, i checked.

EDIT: Thanks, problem solved.

Comment: I assume you did properly compile it first with the "javac" command?

Comment: Simple - javac Assignment02Q01Sec01.java
and then java Assignment02Q01Sec01

Comment: @Voidpaw - I think he did compile it with eclipse. So the answer from David Wallace, Kayaman, Vivek is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run it as

`java hw.Assignment02Q01Sec01`

You have to provide the fully qualified class name and run from bin folder.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd \Users\ghostcow\workspace\hw\bin\
java hw.Assignment02Q01Sec01
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run it from bin, not bin\hw as `java hw.Assignment02Q01Sec01`.

Answer (score 0):

Java program must be run with qualified name of the main class. In this situation, it should be "java hw.Assignment02Q01Sec01 directly outside directory hw(compiled class, not source code)